# Cannot mount /dev/sdb1, getting a bad option, bad superblock error

Tags: linux, partitioning, mount

Trying to mount /dev/sdb1 on my linux server and I am getting the following error. Here is the output of the mount command as well as mount, lsblk, and fdisk -l. I see in fdisk -l that dev/sdb shows a "+" in the blocks column while my other server setup the same way does not but I am unsure of what the means. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
[root@orchestrator1 ~]# mount -t ext4 /dev/sdb1 /media
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb1,
   missing codepage or helper program, or other error
   In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
   dmesg | tail  or so

[root@orchestrator1 ~]# mount
/dev/mapper/vg_orchestrator1-lv_root on / type ext4 (rw)
proc on /proc type proc (rw)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,gid=5,mode=620)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw)
/dev/sda1 on /boot type ext4 (rw)
/dev/mapper/vg_orchestrator1-lv_home on /home type ext4 (rw)
none on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw)
configfs on /sys/kernel/config type configfs (rw)
ocfs2_dlmfs on /dlm type ocfs2_dlmfs (rw)
sunrpc on /var/lib/nfs/rpc_pipefs type rpc_pipefs (rw)
nfsd on /proc/fs/nfsd type nfsd (rw)

[root@orchestrator1 ~]# lsblk
NAME                                MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                                   8:0    0 278.9G  0 disk
├─sda1                                8:1    0   500M  0 part /boot
└─sda2                                8:2    0 278.4G  0 part
  ├─vg_orchestrator1-lv_root (dm-0) 252:0    0    50G  0 lvm  /
  ├─vg_orchestrator1-lv_swap (dm-1) 252:1    0  23.6G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  └─vg_orchestrator1-lv_home (dm-4) 252:4    0 204.8G  0 lvm  /home
sdb                                   8:16   0   2.5T  0 disk
└─sdb1                                8:17   0     2T  0 part
sr0                                  11:0    1  1024M  0 rom

[root@orchestrator1 ~]# fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 299.4 GB, 299439751168 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 36404 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000d0e98

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1          64      512000   83  Linux
Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sda2              64       36405   291908608   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/sdb: 2698.6 GB, 2698581639168 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 328083 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000cba21

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1               1      267347  2147460906+  83  Linux

Disk /dev/mapper/vg_orchestrator1-lv_root: 53.7 GB, 53687091200 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 6527 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000


Disk /dev/mapper/vg_orchestrator1-lv_swap: 25.4 GB, 25367150592 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 3084 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000


Disk /dev/mapper/vg_orchestrator1-lv_home: 219.9 GB, 219857027072 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 26729 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000



(parted) select /dev/sdb
Using /dev/sdb
(parted) print
Model: Dell VIRTUAL DISK (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 2699GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      32.3kB  2199GB  2199GB  primary  ext4
```

Comment: Is the /dev/sdb  on mbr or gpt ?

Comment: Has the disk been formatted? The partition is marked as 83 Linux, but I'm not sure the disk has been formatted too. Something like `sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb1'

Comment: ***DO NOT*** issue a `mkfs` (or `mkfs.ext4`) command on the partition if you've already stored data on it! This command will *erase* **all data** on the partition. This action is appropriate if the partition has not been used before, though. If it *has* been used, then the filesystem is most likely damaged. The `fsck` command (e.g., `fsck /dev/sdb1`) may fix the problem, but even that poses some risks, so if possible a low-level backup (`sudo dd if=/dev/sdb1 of=/path/to/lots/of/space/backup.img`) may be a wise precaution.

Comment: are you sure sdb1 is an ext4 partition? Maybe try ext3 and ext2 as well - they all look the same in fdisk (assuming you **know** that the partition was properly formatted before).

Comment: From the output of parted I thought I did have it formatted and as ext4, but apparently not, this was a new partition so using mkfs was not harmful in my case.  mkfs.ext /dev/sdb1 was the fix and then I was able to issue my mount command